# How to have shared contents in web controls?

Tags: asp.net, reusability, dotnetnuke-module, asp.net-webcontrol

I am working on a DotNetNuke module that obviously uses web controls to show different pages.

I would like to have some shared content on all pages(web controls). In fact I am using bootstrap to render my menu items which it has a markup like this :

```
<div id="pageWrapper" class="active">
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        my menu content
    </div>
    <!-- Page content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <!-- Keep all page content within the page-content inset div! -->
    </div>
</div>
```

So what I really want is to have a way to have this markup in all of my web controls and to be able to put the control content in the page content section.

If I could use pages I would use a master page to achieve this but the question is how can I do the same with web controls ?

Comment: You can have base control with the base functionality, and have your other controls to inherit from it

Comment: but the derived controls only inherit the code behind features and not the designer elements.

Comment: if you create a custom server control (the one that compiles into dll) ,then you can extend it and inherit from it. It may sound complicated, but not really. 
http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Custom-Server-Controls.aspx

Comment: Yes I was aware of this solution but as you mentioned it is really complicated specially when you are dealing with other run at server controls :)